# Core Data Validation Method Not Being Called - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject subclass and I am trying to get data validation to work using the following method in this subclass :

```
- (BOOL)validatefirstName:(NSString *)ioValue error : (NSError **)outError {
NSLog(@"Validating First Name");
return YES;
}
```

The problem is that this method is not triggering when a new value is saved to this class. Should this method be called automatically when I change the value of an attribute within it, or do I need to call another method first ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the method right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation method signature is not valid. Should be as:

```
- (BOOL)validateFirstName:(NSString *)ioValue error : (NSError **)outError
```

For more info refer to [Validation Method Naming Convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173-CJBDBHCB).